# ToString() override

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

We have this class

```
public class BranchCity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we expose data by this class in UI, we often use just `Name` property of it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Branch city
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Model?.BranchCity?.Name
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it be acceptable to override `ToString()` of the class printing out just this property?

```
public override string ToString() => Name ?? "";
```

I've read in many sources that it is a good practice to override `ToString()` with all properties of a class for debugging purposes (for example, it's easy to see the text representation in `Quick Watch` window in VS) but I'm not sure about the way above.

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{nameof(Id)}: {Id}, {nameof(Name)}: {Name}";
}
```

Comment: Do what suits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be acceptable to override ToString() of the class printing out just this property?

```
public override string ToString() => Name ?? "";
```

In my opinion: no.

Sure, you can now do this in your view:

```
@Model?.BranchCity
```

But if you later read that code, you're going to wonder: what will be printed here? So you'll have to go to the definition of `BranchCity`, notice the `ToString()` override and read the code to see which properties it prints. All the time you've saved by not having to write `?.Name` is now lost.

And if in another place you want to print more properties of `BranchCity`, for example because you want to see its Id in some backoffice interface, and you modify it to `Tostring() => $"{Name} ({Id})"`, then *everywhere* where you've used `@SomeModel.BranchCity`, now this `(Id)` suffix will be printed as well.

And if you implement this pattern for a handful of models, you'll have to implement it for all of your models. Otherwise you, or some other collaborator, will expect it to work for other classes as well, use `@SomeModel.SomeOtherProperty`, and see that property's classname printed if you forget to override `ToString()`.

So just don't, and be explicit in which properties you want to print.

For the debugging case I also advocate agains overriding `ToString()`, but use `[DebuggerDisplay]` instead:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public class BranchCity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => $"Id: {id}, Name: {Name}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do whatever you want with your `ToString()` overrides.  Don't let anyone tell you you can't.

Seriously though, there's no convention.  Do whatever your application needs.